# Tuple {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order} being returned for error reason from OAuth2 package

Tags: oauth-2.0, elixir, phoenix-framework

The Phoenix application I'm supporting has OAuth authentication using two different authentication servers. Mysteriously, only in my development environment they have begun exhibiting unexpected behaviour.

The code uses the [OAuth2 hex package](https://hex.pm/packages/oauth2) for authentication.

When an attempt is made to get a token via `OAuth2.Client.get_token/1`, an error is returned with a tuple rather than a string for the reason. The value of the tuple is `{:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}`. I haven't been able to find out why this is happening nor what the tuple means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discovered that this was caused by https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/issues/591 following an upgrade on my machine to Erlang 22.1.

Answer (score 5):

Without having to downgrade your erlang version, try:

`mix deps.update hackney`